# How to schedule repeating local notification for a specific time interval

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I want to schedule local notification for every **3 hours** difference.
But with one limitation, this should be between **7AM - 10PM**

Code for scheduling.

```
let user = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Local Notification"
content.body = "Test."

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (3*60*60), repeats: true)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "id", content: content, trigger: trigger)

user.add(request) { (error) in print("Error")}
```